# How to document a "Baby Scan"?

Tags: birth-records, images, medicine

We had the scan for our second son back on 2nd September 2003. And I still have the digital image and was thinking of adding it to his profile. But since this is an event that occurs before his birth I was not sure of the right way to go about documenting it correctly.

---

At the moment I have just added the digital scan as a photo with the date and location. I have not tried to link it to any fact or anything.

Comment: profile on family-search?

Comment: @depperm I have none of my tree on Family Search because I want it private.

Comment: I'm asking about what type of profile are you referring to (person files, some other site(ancestry/familysearch))?

Comment: @depperm Ah, I have Ancestry, Family Tree Make and Roots Magic.

Answer (score 3):

I would question the genealogical relevance of a baby scan. It is essentially just a photo, just as that photo of your son's third birthday, or the first time he rode a bike. These photos are not added as facts, because they are not of much genealogical relevance. So the most logical place to put it is just as an image or media.

Certainly this baby scan is part of your family history. If you decide to author a book or publication about your recent family history then this scan could be an interesting image to include.

As for adding this to your tree, presumably a young person's profile is private except for any close relatives you might grant access to living person data. There will be very few people who see this, so it is really up to you how you present the image.

And finally, just a note of privacy. An ultrasound scan is harmless enough, but it is medical data. Of course, it is not uncommon for people to post their baby's ultrasound on social media these days. But your son is nearly of age, and could reasonably object to having such an image posted in some public way. In any case, get permission of the subject before posting any images of living persons to your family tree.

Comment: Valid comments and I agree with your logical thinking. Please note that my tree is private and only family members have access to view it. That's how I want it to stay.